# longest path transversals

Tags: graph-theory

In a connected graph any two longest paths intersect at a common vertex. It is open whether any three longest paths in a connected graph intersect at a common vertex. For a connected graph $G$, let the  *longest path transversal number* $\text{lpt}(G)$ be the minimum size of a set of vertices in $G$ that intersects every longest path in $G$. I have seen various papers that bound $\text{lpt}(G)$ for graphs $G$ in various classes. But I have found no paper that addresses the following basic question: Is there a constant $c$ such that $\text{lpt}(G)\leqslant c$ for every connected graph $G$? Does anyone have an answer to this question?

Comment: I co-supervised a student on that conjecture (which remains open) and I also don't recall any results of that nature. My guess is that there is no such $c$ but I can't justify it.

Comment: I have a non-exhaustive collection of 13 million graphs up to 23 vertices without a transversal of size 1. They all have a transversal of size 2.

Comment: Strangely, I just came across this paper two days ago: https://math.wvu.edu/~kgmilans/research/sublin-lpt/sublin-lpt.pdf

They don't prove a constant upper bound, but a sublinear one

Comment: also from that linked paper, they mention that Grunbaum constructed an example requiring a traversal of size 3, and that it is open if 3 is sufficient.