# Do longest paths in 4-connected graphs intersect?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Is there for every $k$ a $k$-connected graph whose longest paths do not have a vertex in common?

This is known to be true for $k\le 3$, see
[Ayesha Shabbir, Carol T. Zamfirescu., Tudor I. Zamfirescu: Intersecting longest paths and longest cycles: A survey](http://tzamfirescu.tricube.de/TZamfirescu-195.pdf).
Surprisingly, nothing is mentioned about $k\ge 4$, though the question kind of appears on p. 232 of
[Tudor I. Zamfirescu: On longest paths and circuits in graphs](http://tzamfirescu.tricube.de/TZamfirescu-067.pdf).

Some related questions include Hippchen's conjecture (any two longest paths intersect in at least $k$ vertices in a $k$-connected graph) and the problem of determining the minimum size of a hitting point set for longest paths, about which there is a [recent MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453558/longest-path-transversals).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Gallai’s question and constructions of almost hypotraceable graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X18300805)
 by Wiener and Zamfirescu, this is an open problem (see the beginning of Section 4).  Note that a graph is $G$ *hypotraceable* if $G$ is not Hamiltonian, but $G-v$ is Hamiltonian for every $v \in V(G)$.  Thus, the existence of a $4$-connected hypotraceable graph would give a negative answer to the question in your title.  However, as also noted at the beginning of Section 4, it is unknown if there are $4$-connected hypotraceable graphs.  Indeed, it is not even known if there are hypotraceable graphs with minimum degree $4$.