# Do vertex-maximal paths in 4-connected graphs intersect?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Call a path in a (possibly infinite) graph *vmax* (for *vertex-maximal*) if there is no path that covers a containmentwise larger subset of vertices.
For example, in any spider graph the union of any two legs is a vmax path.

> Is it true that any two vmax paths intersect in any $k$-connected graph if $k$ is large enough?

I would guess that the answer is no, but I only have a counterexample for $k\le 2$.
Even the following stronger statement could be true for $k\ge 4$.

> Is it true that there is a vertex contained in all vmax paths in any 4-connected graph?

If instead of vmax paths we consider longest paths in finite graphs, then the problem is [open](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456125/do-longest-paths-in-4-connected-graphs-intersect).
This question about vmax paths would be a strengthening of the question about longest paths.

ps. It is NP-hard to show that a path is not vmax by giving a path that covers a larger set of vertices, as otherwise we could solve Hamiltonicity.